# Can't create, open, write files in python

Tags: python, file

```
f = open("demofile3.txt", "w")
f.writelines(["\nSee you soon!", "\nOver and out."])
f.close()
```

`

I have been trying to create or open a file and write something in it but it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Put `import os; print(os.getcwd())` at the top of your code, then see what that prints. Does it print the directory you expected? If you check the directory it prints, is your output file there?

Comment: No it actually prints other directory, but it was not like this couple days ago. Can you tell me how to switch it back please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's about pwd.

But here is a method: use full path.

For example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
folder = Path(__file__).parent
your_txt = folder / "demofile3.txt"
with open(your_txt, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(["\nSee you soon!", "\nOver and out."])
```